# should I insert data into table using php or my sql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I was wondering should I use procedures in mySql or direct from php to populate the table named Project. I have `$projectName`, `$startDate` etc. should I call a `mySql procedure` or directly using php?

For example:

```
        $queryInsert ="INSERT INTO users  (name) 
        VALUES('".$projectName."')";
        //and so on for the rest of vars
```

Wondering which is the best coding practice method to use. 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Definitely `stored procedure` for this operation is the best method to avoid `inline query` and editing from code.

For faster execution and prevent SQL injection you should practice this.

**Impact of inline query:**

1) inline queries are tough to edit you know.

2) can sql injection

3) php and mysql code really get congested.

4) and PHP parser need to make the full query dynamically to execute in mysql

Comment: thanks very much, just wanted to be sure. What would be consequences of inline query?

Answer (score 1):

Some benefits of `stored procedure` are :

- Maintainability: you can change the logic in the procedure without
  needing to edit app1, app2 and app3 calls.
- Security/Access Control: it's easier to worry about who can call a
  predefined procedure than it is to control who can access which
  tables or which table rows.
- Performance: if your app is not situated on the same server as your
  DB, and what you're doing involves multiple queries, using a
  procedure reduces the network overhead by involving a single call to
  the database, rather than as many calls as there are queries.
- Performance (2): a procedure's query plan is typically cached,
  allowing you to reuse it again and again without needing to
  re-prepare it.